# Output array without numeric index

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code:

```
    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
         a = {};
         a['name' + i] = i;
        data.push(a);
}
```

...outputs the following array:

```
{
1:{name0:0},
2:{name1:1},
3:{name2:2}
}
```

How can I amend the code so that it outputs the array as follows:

```
{
name0:0,
name1:1,
name2:2
}
```

The reason I need to do this, is that I'd like to be able to reference my array later on like so: `data[name1]`, instead of having to loop through the entire array to look for the value that I need.

Comment: Use a plain object instead of an array `data = {}` and then use `data['name' + i] = i` in the loop. You don't need `a`.

Comment: they don't need to push;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well you should use data directly as an object, rather than having it as an array (and thus having it as an array of objects)

```
 for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    data['name' + i] = i;
}
```

Keep in mind that data should be an object (initialized as `var data = {}`)

Comment: This is the correct answer. My mistake was trying to push the values into the array each time. I will accept this answer as correct.

Comment: Do you need to initialize `data` ... `var data = {};`? OP has not shown how `data` is initialized but from the operations it's `var data = [];`.